# Xen not in grub menu after do-release-upgrade to 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, xen

I have a server on which I run a number of Xen VMs. I recently upgraded from 16.04 through to 20.04. Unfortunately, Xen is no longer showing up in grub as a boot option. I only see:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Obviously, I can't do anything with Xen at this point (complains it can't find hypervisor in sysfs).

Looking at the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I found that there's no output from `/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen` (output is manually transcribed, apologies for typos):

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
```

The contents of `/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen` match those of a clean install (in a VM), verified by md5sum. How do I get the output to go into `grub.cfg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the upgrade, my xen install appears to have disappeared rather than being upgraded to 4.11. I installed Xen 4.11, and found that `update-grub` correctly populated the option to boot with Xen.

For those who are interested, I ended up diving into `/etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen` and found that `$xen_list` was empty (it gets populated by files matching glob `/boot/xen*`). This led me to check the contents of /boot:

```
config-4.15.0-129-generic  initrd.img-3.19.0-71-generic   initrd.img-5.4.0-59-generic  memtest86+.elf                 System.map-5.4.0-59-generic
config-5.4.0-59-generic    initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic   lost+found                   memtest86+_multiboot.bin       vmlinuz-4.15.0-129-generic
grub                       initrd.img-4.15.0-129-generic  memtest86+.bin               System.map-4.15.0-129-generic  vmlinuz-5.4.0-59-generic
```

Nothing matching `xen*`! And my clean install in a VM on my workstation had files matching `xen-4.11-amd64.*`. A simple invocation of `apt install xen-hypervisor-4.11-amd64` resolved my issue.